# Unusual resource handling in SharePoint?

Tags: localization, resource-files

In ASP.NET, WinForms and others, resource management is pretty well thought of and documented. When I have xxx.hu.resx (a neutral culture) and the current culture is hu-HU (a specific culture), the fallback process will find xxx.hu.resx instead of xxx.hu-HU.resx.

In Sharepoint, there are so called provisioning resources in the Resources folder, pretty distinct from ASP.NET global resources. They are used by Sharepoint interally when displaying feature titles etc., and by SPUtility.GetLocalizedString. I failed to find specific documentation regarding my questions.

I have a hu-HU Sharepoint site collection and I deployed a dummy feature with a neutral (Resources.hu.resx) and an invariant culture (Resources.resx). Sharepoint simply wouldn't display the neutral resource, only the invariant one. When I added a specific culture (Resources.hu-HU.resx), it is displayed just fine. Looks like the specific-neutral fallback process is missing.

I also tried applying a NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute to the solution assembly, tried every combination of the neutral culture, the fallback location and site collection language, and it simply didn't change a thing. Looks like this attribute is not supported at all.

Sadly I have no idea to find out by disassembly how it works because SPUtility.GetLocalizedString calls an unmanaged method.

Did I do something wrong, or did Sharepoint badly reinvent resource management and doesn't support the above stuff?

Comment: sorry but I read your question atleast 10 times, but am still confused whats the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not well documented but SPUtility.GetLocalizedString don't support Language-neutral resources. See [SharePoint SPUtility.GetLocalizedString() Behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cliffgreen/archive/2010/08/31/sharepoint-sputility-getlocalizedstring-behavior.aspx) from Cliff Green's MSDN blog which describes SharePoints very different fallback behavior.

I don't know if SharePoint reinvented or invented the resource management, but as you can see it's using its own implementation.